# Accessing form2 List Elements to mainform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms .. (Form1 and Form 2) in that form 1 is calling form2  for performing some operations, form 2 has list that has some element added to it during operation or runtime, once operation of form 2 are done , i want to copy the form2 list items to list in form1...

i am using **ShowDialog()** for displaying form2, because it is mandatory as per requirement.

please tell me the way to define list so that i can access it elements from form1 which are added in form2.

I don't have any code to paste ... sorry for that...

Comment: does the list items stores in Database(i.e.) U have entered in Form 2

Comment: No, items are not added from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a public list in Form2, and add the items in question to this list once you are done/closing form2.

This will then be accessable from Form1 is Form1 has a reference to the Form2 object.

So in Form2 you could have something like

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public List<string> f2List = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2List.Add(f2List.Count.ToString());
    }
```

and then from Form1 you could try

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        List<string> f1List = f2.f2List;
    }
```

**EDIT**

See *action* for adding items to List in Form2 so they are available in Form1

Comment: i already defined the list as public in form 2,but it is returning zero elements

Comment: You need to assign/add the values to this list at some point during operations in Form2, so that they are available later for form1

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public List<string> f2List = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2List.Add(f2List.Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then from Form1 you could try

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
list<String> copy_of_form2_list;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();

// for copy the object , we serialize and deserialize an object
                try
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    FileStream output = new FileStream("temp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                    formatter.Serialize(output,f2.f2List);
                    output.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                }


                try
                {
                    BinaryFormatter reader = new BinaryFormatter();
                    FileStream input = new FileStream("temp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    fcopy_of_form2_list=((List <String>)reader.Deserialize(input));
                    input.Close();

                    if (File.Exists(@"temp"))
                    {
                        File.Delete(@"temp");
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                }

            List<string> f1List = copy_of_form2_list;
        }
```